Does an Infernal Trove count as an Encounter?
When you get certain items from the Well of Charon or a curse from Chaos it lasts a certain number of Encounters before it wears off. If you activate an Infernal Trove and fight off the enemies that appear, does that count as an Encounter?

No. Infernal Troves do not count as an Encounter for Chaos curses or purchases from the Well of Charon.
